# How to create avoid excel/word exportation from reportviewer

Tags: visual-studio, reportviewer

Is there a way to delete the export options for Excel and Word in MS Reportviewer 2015 ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This works on Windows Forms.

```
Private Sub FmReporViewer_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim exportOption1 As String = "Excel"
        Dim exportOption2 As String = "Word"

        Dim extension1 As RenderingExtension = ReportViewer.LocalReport.ListRenderingExtensions().ToList().Find(Function(x) x.Name.Equals(exportOption1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        If extension1 IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim fieldInfo As System.Reflection.FieldInfo = extension1.GetType().GetField("m_isVisible", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            fieldInfo.SetValue(extension1, False)
        End If
        Dim extension2 As RenderingExtension = ReportViewer.LocalReport.ListRenderingExtensions().ToList().Find(Function(x) x.Name.Equals(exportOption2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        If extension2 IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim fieldInfo As System.Reflection.FieldInfo = extension2.GetType().GetField("m_isVisible", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            fieldInfo.SetValue(extension2, False)
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work, one thing `ReportViewer.LocalReport.ListRenderingExtensions().ToList().Find(Function(x) x.Name.Equals(exportOption1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))`  raise this error: 
Error BC30469 Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference. , so I change it for  **reportviewer1** the name of my control int the webform. Any Idea?

Comment: ReportViewer is the name of the ReportViewer object of your form, in your case the name is reportviewer1. But now that you say it's for WebForms, not if that code will work for you.